# Understanding 見せていただいてて

Tags: particles, expressions, て-form, sentence

While watching a Japanese TV drama I came across this sentence "私こちらのお店を見せていただいてて。。。" as shown in the image below. I can't understand the "見せていただいてて" part. Can anyone please break this part down and explain what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: A little more context would be helpful here - for the line in question, but also for what kind of problem you're having with it. What do you think it means? Are you familiar with the verbs 見せる and いただく involved? What part of their usage here are you unsure about?

Comment: Actually she was interrupted by another person before she can complete the sentence, so the sentence is incomplete. And yes, I was not sure about the verb 見せる, but I know now, it means to show or to display and if used with いただく then it means the first person is being shown something. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「私こちらのお店を見せていただい**てて**・・」

is a colloquial contraction of:

> 「私こちらのお店を見せていただい**ていて**・・」

the last part of which is the te-form for:

> 「いただいている」

It is difficult to translate the phrase because it is not a whole sentence, but it would mean something like:

> "I am having the priviledge of taking a look at this store, and ~~"

Answer (score 1):

"I was kindly shown this store and..."

見せる to show
～ていただく to receive the favor of (an action)
～てform - used to join verbs/adjectives (among other functions)

The sentence is a fragment - do you have the rest of the sentence so we can give a more accurate translation?

Comment: No, someone interrupts the person saying this sentence, so she only says the part of it.

Comment: Anyway, I think your translation is quite accurate, thanks a lot!